# ¿Cómo puedo arreglar la barra donde se ven los warnings/errores de compilación de Dev-C++? ¡Solo aparece en blanco!

Tags: dev-c++

## ¿Cuál es el problema?

#### El problema es el siguiente:

No puedo ver los **errores/warnings** de compilación.

---

Aquí les dejo la **imagen** para que vean lo que sucede.

[image]

Como pueden observar en la **imagen**, no se pueden ver los **errores/warnings** en la **barra**.

---

**Entonces**, ¿cómo puedo **solucionar** este **problema**?

Comment: Explicate mejor, no se entiende, intenta usar las comas. Gracias.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Dale a [edit](/edit) modifica la pregunta siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio, pegando el código como texto y no como imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Eso ya es problema de Dev-C++. Intenta reinstalar Dev-C++, y si sigue persistiendo el problema, instala otra versión; si fuera tú, usaría IDE's/editores de textos más actualizado como:

- Visual Studio Code
- Visual Studio
- Code::Blocks

Dev-C++ es un IDE demasiado viejo; se dejó de desarrollar hace 11 años creo. Tiene muchos problemas y además es muy viejo; por eso dejé de usarlo...

Answer (score 0):

Si es que no dejaste de usarlo, da click derecho a esa tremenda barra y vas a la opción de "Ventana de reporte flotante". A veces confunde porque sale un barra blanca, y se piensa que no es lo que queremos, pero solo es cuestión de agrandar aquella barra y verás que es la ventana que quieres. Luego cierras esa ventana flotante y se anclará automáticamente a donde debería estar.